# Code in comment overflows page horizontally

Tags: bug, comments, code

Look at my comment under [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667414/87996).

[image]

My OS is an up-to-date Archlinux, and the browser is [qutebrowser](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser).

Comment: sounds like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361250/comment-overflow